# Get user agent using img tag

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-web-services, html-email

I'm using a simple img html tag in an email message in order to run an AWS Lambda everytime the message is reading. Img tag is like:

```
<img alt="" src="https://lambda-url?att=data">
```

I can send data to the lambda via url, but I want to be able to pass a full user agent to the lambda, without using a script tag, only with the img tag. How to do that?

Comment: Without a script tag on the client side, it may be possible to check/log how many times the img URL is accessed/loaded, but this would lend itself to the calculated number of "visit" being interfered with by bots or people directly going to the url of the image, it also wouldn't account for a user re-opening an email where the img was cached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything - the user-agent is included in the [event object passed to your script](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#lambda-event-structure-request). I've not used Javascript in Lambda, but in Python, the user-agent is at

```
event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']['headers']['user-agent'][0]['value']
```

I assume you are aware that web bugs are not very reliable indicators.